# Is there a way to control the Home key and the keys in the Phone Window Manager in AndroidTv?

Tags: android, capacitor, android-tv, keyevent, remote-control

I am developing Android Tv.
There are keys in the Home key and Phone Window Manager from the remote control, but I don't know how to control them.

Even if I change the source of the Phone Window Manager, the Log is not photographed in apk and debug, is there a way to apply that part?